# Should I now include these files in my [InstallDelete] section since they are no longer required?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have commented the following items out of my `[Files]` section in my script:

```
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook RTL.css"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook RTL.xsl"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook.css"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook.xsl"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook-off.css"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook-off-12h.xsl"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook-off-12h-PublicTalks.xsl"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook-off-24h.xsl"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
; Source: "{#InnoPath}\Scripts--Workbook\Workbook-off-PublicTalks.css"; DestDir: "{#CommonDataDir}"; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly touch; Attribs: readonly
```

`{#CommonDataDir}` is defined like this:

```
#define MSA "Meeting Schedule Assistant"
#define CommonDataDir "{commonappdata}\" + MSA
```

Now, my question concerns when users are upgrading my software. Does this mean that I should now replicate the above files in the `[InstallDelete]` section since they are no longer required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to get rid of them.

The installer won't delete them on its own, only because they are no longer included in the `[Files]` section – Unless your installer runs uninstaller first.